# python json load set encoding to utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
keys_file = open("keys.json")
keys = keys_file.read().encode('utf-8')
keys_json = json.loads(keys)
print(keys_json)
```

There are some none-english characters in keys.json.
But as a result I get:

```
[{'category': 'РјР±С‚', 'keys': ['Р‘Р»РµРЅРґРµСЂ Philips',
'РјСѓР»СЊС‚РёРІР°СЂРєР° Polaris']}, {'category': 'РљР‘Рў', 'keys':
['С…РѕР»РѕРґ РёР»СЊРЅРёРє Р°С‚Р»Р°РЅС‚', 'РїРѕСЃСѓРґРѕРјРѕРµС‡РЅР°СЏ
РјР°С€РёРЅР° Bosch']}]
```

what do I do?

Comment: What do you want to do? Remove non-ASCII characters?

Comment: I want to display them to normal language not list of rundom not understandable symbols

Comment: @user2950593 You've specified the `utf-8` encoding. Is that the encoding of the file?

Comment: what is the encoding of "keys.json", utf-8?

Comment: @georgexsh how do I check it? I am using windows 10

Comment: @StefanPochmann it was mistake. corrected it

Comment: What happens if you open the file as a binary file, instead of decoding and re-encoding?

Comment: `encode` means *characters to binary*. What you want when *reading* a file is *binary to characters* → `decode`.

Comment: @deceze Isn't the decoding done automatically?

Comment: @Stefan *It depends.* It it was, it makes no sense to re-encode the data back to binary.

Comment: @deceze When is it not done automatically?

Comment: @Stefan Okay, a little bit of back-pedalling here. By default it is decoded, yes. *It depends* on what it is decoded as (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns) is what I should have said. Additionally I wasn't *really* advocating that OP call `decode`, I wanted to point out that they're doing the logically wrong operation to begin with.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

`encode` means *characters to binary*. What you want when *reading* a file is *binary to characters* → `decode`. But really this entire process is way too manual, simply do this:

```
with open('keys.json', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)

print(data)
```

`with` handles the correct opening and closing of the file, the `encoding` argument to `open` ensures the file is read using the correct encoding, and the `load` call reads directly from the file handle instead of storing a copy of the file contents in memory first.

If this still outputs invalid characters, it means your source encoding isn't UTF-8 or your console/terminal doesn't handle UTF-8.

Comment: what does fh stand for?

Comment: "File handle". You can choose any other name you want. It's more descriptive than "keys_file" though. Also note that "`data`" is much more appropriate a name than "keys_json"; when you have loaded the JSON data it's not JSON anymore, it's a Python list/dict.

Comment: How would you achieve this in py2?

Comment: @Akbar No. `load` reads from a file pointer, efficiently. `loads` reads from a string, which is less efficient if you read the file into memory first and then parse it as a string from there.